# How to find this : $\sum^n_{r=1} \int^{(2r-1)\pi}_0 f(sin^4x)dx =$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to find this : 
$\sum^n_{r=1} \int^{(2r-1)\pi}_0 f(sin^4x)dx =$

Is it periodic function, please elaborate on this , will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing here is that $$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(\sin^4x)dx = \int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin^4x)dx$$
This can be seen by substituting $t = x -n\pi$ in the integral, and showing that $\sin^4(t+n\pi) = (-\sin(t))^4 = \sin^4t$

Thus, as $$\int_0^{(2r-1)\pi} fdx= \sum_{n=0}^{2r-2}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} fdx$$ we get -
$$\int_0^{(2r-1)\pi} fdx= (2r-1)\int_{0}^{\pi} fdx$$
So, the sum becomes -
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{r=1} \int^{(2r-1)\pi}_0 f(sin^4x)dx 
&= \sum^n_{r=1} (2r-1)\int^{\pi}_0 f(sin^4x)dx \\
&= n^2\int^{\pi}_0 f(sin^4x)dx \\
\end{align}